# Dell Inspiron laptop won't connect to the internet through WiFi after driver update

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 laptop with Windows 10. I recently had a 4G portable router, which is Dlink DWR-932M-9332. My phone is connecting to the router just fine. However, after a driver update to the Intel wireless AC 9462 adapter through software called Driver Booster, the Wifi in my laptop keeps getting disconnected and won't open any web pages. Also, I've tried pinging Google and Facebook through the command prompt and the laptop won't ping. It is worth noting that when I tether my laptop to the phone through USB, everything is working fine.
Here's what I have tried to do so far:

1. Resetting network stack and flushing DNS
2. Reinstalling network devices from the Windows settings
3. Disabling and enabling the WiFi adapter
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling the adapter's driver
5. Resetting the entire laptop to a previous system image

Comment: Try a USB wireless device and see if that works.

Comment: uninstall the driver from DB and get one from the Dell site. https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us